# R strange apply returns

Tags: r

I use apply to a matrix in order to apply a function row by row.
My syntax is as follows :

```
res = apply(X,1,MyFunc)
```

The above function MyFunc returns a list of two values.
But the result of this apply application is a strange structure, where R seems to add some of its own (housekeeping?) data :

```
res = $`81`
$`81`$a
[1] 80.8078

$`81`$b
[1] 6247
```

Whereas the result I am waiting for is simply :

```
res = $a
[1] 80.8078

$b
[1] 6247
```

I do not know why this strange `81` is inserted by R and how can I get rid of it.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

This is perfectly normal behaviour. You are applying a function over a matrix with named rows. Your function returns a list for each row, and each element in this new list of lists is named with the corresponding rowname.

Here is an example that reproduces what you describe:

```
x <- matrix(1:4, nrow=2)
rownames(x) <- 80:81

myFunc <- function(x)list(a=1, b=2)

xx <- apply(x, 1, myFunc)
xx
```

This returns:

```
$`80`
$`80`$a
[1] 1

$`80`$b
[1] 2


$`81`
$`81`$a
[1] 1

$`81`$b
[1] 2
```

Take a look at the structure of this list:

```
str(xx)
List of 2
 $ 80:List of 2
  ..$ a: num 1
  ..$ b: num 2
 $ 81:List of 2
  ..$ a: num 1
  ..$ b: num 2
```

To index the first element, simply use `xx[[1]]`:

```
xx[[1]]
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2
```

---

Here is a guess as to what you may have intended...  Rather than returning a list, if you return a vector, the result of the `apply` will be a matrix:

```
myFunc <- function(x)c(a=1, b=2)
apply(x, 1, myFunc)
  80 81
a  1  1
b  2  2
```

---

And to get a specific row, without names, do:

```
unname(xx[2, ])
[1] 2 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I noticed that xx[[1]] gave me my result. How can I make it for the hole return of my apply? I tried to use sapply(xx,"[[") but could not retrieve my result.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... You have created a function to return a list of lists. Each element is named the same as the row in the original array. What is the expected result you want?

Comment: I want for example a vector of lists containing the attributes a, and b. As you noticed, I can access the first element of this vector of list by typing xx[[1]], which gives me the list of two items a and b, but I want all of the lists. I tried xx[[1:length(xx)]] but it does not work

Comment: @volatile My guess is that you want a matrix as the returned value instead of a list of lists. I have edited my answer to show how to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is better now. I get a matrix with named rows and columns. How can I get a particular row without the names?

Comment: @volatile, if it is exactly what you were looking for, do be sure to accept and/or up-vote the answer. This helps us focus on addressing unanswered questions in the R tag.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know what your matrix (`X`) looks like. Let's try something like this:

```
mf <- function(x) list(a=sum(x),b=prod(x))
mat <- matrix(1:6,nrow=2)
```

Then:

```
> apply(mat,1,mf)
[[1]]
[[1]]$a
[1] 9

[[1]]$b
[1] 15


[[2]]
[[2]]$a
[1] 12

[[2]]$b
[1] 48
```

You need that first subscript to differentiate between the lists that each row will generate. I suspect that your rownames are numbered, which results in the `` $`81` `` that you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. It seems we are converging to a solution